# Jesus' baptism in Spirit and fire in the light of the Isaianic new exodus

Tags: luke, isaiah

Many today recognize that Luke follows the Isaianic new exodus for his Luke-Acts narrative. So, what it is the meaning of Jesus' baptism in Spirit/fire (Luke 3:16; Acts 1:8) in the light of this? (perhaps from Isaiah 59:16-21; Isaiah 61:1-3)?

In Acts 1, after Jesus presents himself to his disciples for 40 days, speaking of the kingdom, He uses the contrast between John's baptism and the baptism in the Holy Spirit. It causes the question about the restoration of the kingdom and Jesus replies that it is not for them to understand (another contrast), "*but you shall receive power when the Holy Spirit has come upon you; and you shall be My witness both in Jerusalem and in  all Judea and Samaria, and even to the remotest part of the earth.*"

Jesus inserts himself as the mediator of the new covenant of the Spirit. Could this be the fulfillment and paraphrase of "*the redeemer will come to Zion...and this is my covenant with them - I will put my Spirit upon you and my words in your mouth...forever*" (Isaiah 59:21-22)?

In verses 15b through 18 of Isaiah 59 there is a reference to judgement. Perhaps this was alluded to in "baptism of fire" fulfilled immediately against the power brokers of Jerusalem and later in final judgement.  I am working on this.

Just thought I would expand so as to not leave the question hanging. I will try to write my questions better in the future.

Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I have reformatted the question to make it more readable. You need to indicate what version of the Bible you are quoting. It looks like the SDA Clear Word Bible.  You also should explain something about "Isaianic new exodus" rather than force your readers to do their own research as they will likely ignore the question, or even downvote it as needing clarity.

Answer (score -1):

The world will be destroyed or refined by fire. Look at the test given to the Father of Israel, Abraham and in a similar event to Meshach, Shadrach and Abednego.

We are to watch signs in the sky. On the future birthday of the US on 04 Jul 1054AD a supernova appeared in the sky. Jesus said he was here to recover the lost house of Israel.

In 722BC the northern Kingdom of Israel was destroyed. It essentially started the diaspora. From 722BC to 1054AD is 1776 years. Now add 722 years to the supernova event. It is the exact birthday of the US.

722 is an interesting number. 22/7 = pi. The masons starts time at 4000BC. 4000 + 1776 = 5776. 5776 / 722 = 8. The masons are luciferian and secretly work against Christianity in an attempt to destroy it. The US mystery babylon lie is an endtimes coverup that the tribes are truly spiritual through Jesus Christ. Those in Christ in the US are of Ephraim.

Abraham was born 1948AM. In a parallel event Israel was reborn as a nation in 1948AD. God made a covenant with Abraham in his 75th year. 1948 + 75 = 2023AD. Jesus says we will return to the times of Noah. Methuselah died at the flood. He was 969 years old. 1054AD + 969 = 2023AD.

God told Noah in postflood covenant that he would endure with flesh 120 years. 1656AM (flood year) + 120 = 1776 years. My research from meditation on Jeremiah 33:3 shows the Anno Domini age as a time parallel from Creation to the Father of Israel Abraham. It appears a mudflood occurred in 1656AD in the covered up kingdom of Tartaria (chains of tartarus?) where the nephilim had returned to earth.

Enoch ascended to Heaven 987AM. Now take the reverse of 789 years and add it to it. 987 + 789 = 1776. In 1789 George Washington was inaugurated and the US Constitution was ratified.